# R latex2exp, Error in str2expression(rendered): "could not find function "str2expression"

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, latex2exp

I am trying to write LaTex formulas in ggplot titles and labels by using `Tex` function from `latex2exp`,
like

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(latex2exp)

x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(10, 3, 2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = x, y = y), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = TeX("$s^2$"))
```

which results in
`Error in str2expression(rendered): "could not find function "str2expression"`. How can I fix it?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: @stefan sorry, I fixed it

Comment: Works fine using R 4.1.2, ggplot2 3.3.5, latex2exp 0.9.3 on my Mac.

Comment: You likely need to update your packages.  Use `update.packages(ask=FALSE)` to do that.  If it still fails, you'll need to update R as well.